PrismaClientKnownRequestError: Invalid `prisma.rEF_DOMAIN.findMany()` invocation:
When I run npm run build in my cmd, I got error below.
Error occurred prerendering page "/admin/user/cltp4kd9j0020mkiisgqsjgsu". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
Invalid `prisma.rEF_DOMAIN.findMany()` invocation:


Can't reach database server at `my_DB_URL`

Please make sure your database server is running at `my_DB_URL`.
    at Mn.handleRequestError (C:\Users\HP ProBook 430 G7\Desktop\Github\Usdp\Usdp\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:121:7338)
    at Mn.handleAndLogRequestError (C:\Users\HP ProBook 430 G7\Desktop\Github\Usdp\Usdp\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:121:6663)    
    at Mn.request (C:\Users\HP ProBook 430 G7\Desktop\Github\Usdp\Usdp\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:121:6370)
    at async l (C:\Users\HP ProBook 430 G7\Desktop\Github\Usdp\Usdp\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:130:9633)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
    at async q (C:\Users\HP ProBook 430 G7\Desktop\Github\Usdp\Usdp\.next\server\app\(dashboard)\admin\user\[id]\page.js:1:53887)
Export encountered an error on /(dashboard)/admin/user/[id]/page: /admin/user/cltp4kd9j0020mkiisgqsjgsu, exiting the build.
 ⨯ Static worker exited with code: 1 and signal: null

I already test the connection and it successfully connected. So, I believe it is not because of connection issue. I am using NextJS and prisma. Why this happen?
